# Finding the container id of a customer docker image running under Azure app service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

We just deployed our custom docker image on Azure Webapp services. I think the docker is running fine but we need to know the container-id of the specific webapp service.

We checked the logs on Azure portal for the app service instance; had no luck.
We tried to SSH to the container to grab the container ID; had a "connection refused" error.

Does anyone know how to easily grab the container id of a webapp that runs based on docker on Azure?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by container id? The Web App instance id? And what s the reason that you need to know the container id?

Comment: We deployed the web app service based on our docker image in our Azure private registry. Since they started the WEB app from a docker image, there must be a container ID somewhere for that docker container.

Comment: What do you want to use it for? You know you cannot run the docker command to get the container id in the web app. What you can get are the things I said in the answer.

Comment: By design, we are using the the container ID as part of device verification. We need to know that piece of information in order to authorize the services for the device. This works well in VM environments because we have access to docker commands. We learned that we could run containers as web apps on Azure so wanted to give it a shot but it looks like unless we change our workflow we will not be able to use the app services for this purpose.

Comment: If you mean the container id that you can use the command `docker ps` to get, then Azure Web App cannot show you the container id. And if the answer is helpful for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by container id, but what you can get from the Web App are the instance id and container name. Both of them you can get from the logs in the container setting.

And that you want to connect to the container but it failed. The reason is that you didn't enable the SSH in your custom image. You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh) to enable the SSH in the custom image.